# Как сделать маленькое окошко по середине Android

Tags: android

Как сделать маленькое окошко типо Dialog по середине экрана Android, поверх всех окон. Допустим когда приходит смс, типо USSD то появляется Dialog по середине

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А чем именно диалог не устраивает?

Comment: Dialog же в самом активити отображается, а мне надо чтобы допустим приложение было закрыто или свернуто и Dialog появился поверх экрана

Comment: То есть по идее у Вас должен быть некий BroadcastReceiver, который слушает определенное событие. В нем диалог вызывайте собсна.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Установи тему в манифесте для этого активити. Пропиши типа: 
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"

ВОТ картинка

Comment: А как убрать ActionBar у диалога?

Comment: у него как бы не должно быть ActionBar'a.

Comment: Но оно есть....

Comment: <style name="DialogNotification" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

Это не помогает

Comment: Скинул картинку, видите вверху Title видно.